# How to correctly create saved_model.pb?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have been trying to create a `saved_model.pb` file (from `.ckpt`, `.meta` files) that is needed in order to do inference. I can successfully create a file which contains `saved_model.pb` and variables, however when I deploy my script, I get a `KeyError` on the expected tensors:

```py
y_probs = [my_predictor._fetch_tensors['y_prob_{}'.format(p)] for p in protocols]

KeyError: 'y_prob_protocol1'
```

The problem is probably in how I've defined my inputs/outputs (see code at the end) because the feed and fetch tensors are empty as you can see below:

```py
my_predictor = predictor.from_saved_model('export')

SavedModelPredictor with feed tensors {} and fetch_tensors {}
```

```py
saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(opts.model)
builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(opts.out_path)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Restore variables from disk.
    saver.restore(sess, opts.checkpoint)
    print("Model restored.")

    input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,128,128,128,1), name='tensors/component_0')
    tensor_1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,128,128,128,2), name='pred/Reshape')
    tensor_2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None,128,128,128,3), name='pred1/Reshape')


    tensor_info_input = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(input_tensor)
    tensor_info_1 = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(tensor_1)
    tensor_info_2 = tf.saved_model.utils.build_tensor_info(tensor_2)


    prediction_signature = (
        tf.saved_model.signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
            inputs={'x': tensor_info_input},
            outputs={'y_prob_protocol1': tensor_info_1, 'y_prob_protocol2':tensor_info_2},
            method_name=tf.saved_model.signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME))

    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
        sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
        signature_def_map={
            'predict_images':
                prediction_signature,
        })

    builder.save()
```

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there might be 2 reasons for this error:

1. The Restored Model (Saved using Check Points) might not be properly linked to the `builder.save()`'s, `saved_model.pb` file.
2. You have used 2 outputs, `tensor_info_1` and `tensor_info_2` in the SignatureDef. But they are not defined (at least in the code shown). By definition, I mean something, like,

   `y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, w) + b, name='y')`.

You can use this simple script to convert from Checkpoints and Meta Files to .pb file. But you must specify the names of the output nodes.

```
import tensorflow as tf

meta_path = 'model.ckpt-22480.meta' # Your .meta file
output_node_names = ['output:0']    # Output nodes

with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Restore the graph
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(meta_path)

    # Load weights
    saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('.'))

    # Freeze the graph
    frozen_graph_def = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
        sess,
        sess.graph_def,
        output_node_names)

    # Save the frozen graph
    with open('output_graph.pb', 'wb') as f:
      f.write(frozen_graph_def.SerializeToString())
```

This conversion is too much of work. Instead of Saving the Model to `Check Points` and then trying to convert it to `.pb file`, you can Save the Model, Graphs and the `SignatureDefs` directly to `.pb file` either using `SavedModelBuilder` or using `export_saved_model`.

Example code for Saving a Model using `SavedModelBuilder` is given in the below link.

It is the official code provided by Google Tensorflow Serving Team and following this code (flow and structure) would be recommended.

https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_saved_model.py